# What hexes should I take for my huckster?

Tags: spells, deadlands-classic

I'm in a **Deadlands** game using the classic Pinnacle rules set. Our posse is fairly well mixed — two or three gunslingers of varying types, a sharpshooter, a voudonista, a mad scientist, and me. What hexes should I take to complement the other party members? So far, I've got:

- *Corporeal Twist* (to make opponents less adept at dodging and shooting)
- *Mental Tweak* (to boost my low Spirit, Mien, and Cognition in relevant circumstances, including...)
- *Soul Blast* (to deal damage in circumstances where we need to take out a single target without harming the surroundings)
- *Hunch* (because postcognition is a great way to get clues)
- *Trinkets* (for last-ditch efforts and sheer coolness)

I've got access to both *Hucksters & Hexes* and *Hexarcana*; what are the best spells to take that I don't already have?

Comment: What are your requirements? "Complement the other party members" is vague.

Comment: With several adept gunfighters, we don't need a lot more damage dealt out. With our voudonista, we have healing covered and certain plot-solvers, although there may be room for more. The mad scientist covers non-lethal damage a lot of the time, although he's not terribly focused at it, and tends to do more for sheer coolness. Given these characters, what spells would be useful, helpful, and unlikely to be redundant? Your advice below is quite good; I'm looking to see what else comes from it before the session next week.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The huge variety of hexes means choice is a function of what kind of huckster you want to play. The tweaks, and hunch mean that you want to generally be a helpful buffer to the party. Grab some tricks (there's a huge list), Draw, Hex Sense, Disrupt, Foil, and Achilles Heel to round out the "I'm generally helpful" list. Draw can give you actions, Hex Sense, disrupt and foil mean you can cancel out a fair bit of badness, and Achilles Heel means you can figure out what the rest of the party needs to do to disrupt a baddie.

Looking at [This Conversion Guide](http://members.fortunecity.com/azurian/wwest/deadlands_main.html), here's a long list of hexes I would recommend for different focuses.

- Knowledge:

  - Achilles' Heel: A "How do we beat this?" spell can come in handy, if you're facing that sort of challenge.
  - Blood Hound: great for tracking down bounties
- Camping

  - Critter Ward: should make camping in the wild safer... until you get the critters that *can* cross the ward
- Sneaks

  - Air Bubble: provides all kinds of options for moving through what would be hostile environments. Very valuable to a huckster who likes sneaking
  - Earshot: Great for spyin' all quiet like. Especially into meetings you ain't supposed to be at.
  - Filibuster: mmm, distractions
  - Flypaper fingers:
  - Gateway: just absurd at how useful this is for getting away
  - Ghost trail: when you don't want people following you
  - Home ground: Maps are great, especially when you can get one you didn't previously have
  - Imposter: a different kind of sneak, but handy
  - Incognito
  - Private eye
- Defensive:

  - Bodyguard: If you like bein' shot at, this spells great for making sure the lead don't touch you.
  - Disrupt: Counterspelling ongoing hexes can be right valuable if they're protecting the baddy or hindering you.
  - Diversion: Handy for protecting your buddies
  - Filibuster: mmm, distractions.
  - Foil: the companion to disrupt, this means they don't get the powers out in the first place.
  - Hex Sense: Useful to sense what you want disrupted before it hurts you.
  - Lethargy
- Offensive:

  - Draw!: additional actions are nice, but is the price right?
  - Power Struggle: to help Harrowed get dominion over their demons...